# IntelliJ IDEA - Bold Font Not Working

Tags: intellij-idea

I use bold default text in IntelliJ but after updating to Community Edition 15.0, bold default text doesn't seem to work.

I've created a new Scheme, saved it with bold default text, and it shows up in the preview window as bold, but after clicking Apply and OK, the text in the editor is unchanged.

The default text is located under File - Settings - Editor - Colors and Fonts - General - Text - Default Text

Can anyone with Community Edition 15.0 on a Windows platform (I'm using Windows 8.1) tell me if they see this as well or if they know any workarounds to get the default text to bold?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

In works fine in **IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3** (Windows 7).

Don't forget to **save** your **own scheme** because you can't change the default one.

Then the "**Bold**" option should work.

[image: Save my own scheme]

Comment: I didn't have to override current schema on IntelliJ 2017.2.6 but you showed me where to find the check box  to enable bold font.

Comment: In 2018.2 it is in Settings - Editor - Color Scheme - General - Text - Default text.